# Help me beat my friend at hide-n-seek!

Tags: riddle, word

Throwing back to the days of childhood, I recently challenged my friends to a game of hide-and-seek. As the play area was restricted to my neighborhood, I quickly found all of them. One of my friends, Grey T. Hider, has requested me for a rematch. Being as competitive as I am, I agreed. He proposed a game in which he will spend a week preparing his hiding spot, and will send me an email when he's ready. Once he's hidden I will have one week to find him.

I received Grey's email today, and it seems that he's really intent to prove his superior hiding skills to me. He's offered me a $10,000 dollar reward to find him and has even given me a hint, because he's so sure that I won't find him.

### His email was as follows:

Hi Green, on my way to my hiding spot, I've seen many places and things, some of which were exciting, and some of which were more boring... Because I'm so confident that you would never be able to find me by yourself, I've included a hint, in the form of some things I've seen:

A narrow set of rapids, perfect for rafting

-A river that started flowing off a precipice

--A decrease, concering quantity or quality

---A man having this, resulting in him not playing his best

----A famous painting of people at a bar

-----A heroic archer

------A beautiful woman that looked so sweet

-------A colorful town made of colorful confections

--------A mass of rock sliding down a mountain

---------A powerpoint presentation

----------A platform for actors to play on a river

-----------A comfortable place to live by the water

Good luck finding me! If you can do it within a week of receiving this email I'll reward you with $10,000. If you can't, then you can live knowing that you'll never be as great a hide-and-seeker as I, Grey T. Hider.

Because there's so much riding on this, I request your help to decipher his hint.
Note that the only thing you need to solve this puzzle is his hint of the things and places Grey has seen.

Comment: Our help will cost you 50% of his reward. Still ok?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll find him in the

> white-house

Why?

> Each clue is for a single 2 word(ish) answer, where the second word is the start of the next answer.
>  For the final answer we join the first word of the first answer with the last word of the last answer.

A narrow set of rapids, perfect for rafting

> white-water

-A river that started flowing off a precipice

> water-fall

--A decrease, concerning quantity or quality

> fall-off

---A man having this, resulting in him not playing his best

> off-night

----A famous painting of people at a bar

> Night-Hawks

-----A heroic archer

> Hawk-eye

------A beautiful woman that looked so sweet

> eye-candy

-------A colorful town made of colorful confections

> candy-land

--------A mass of rock sliding down a mountain

> land-slide

---------A powerpoint presentation

> slide-show

----------A platform for actors to play on a river

> show-boat

-----------A comfortable place to live by the water

> boat-house

Comment: Updated after realising I'd accidentally used a plural where I shouldn't have / resulting in 2 other answers coming to me :)

Comment: Ha, great job! I couldn't find the pattern so quickly!

Comment: You're very close! Knowing Grey, there's probably a reason he used - in his email instead of another character like .

Comment: Also, it was my bad on the plural... I forgot the painting name had an s in it

Comment: That's cool - I didn't spot that one; I'd used a shorter answer for the precipice before spotting the path he was taking / left the plural from the shorter answer once I lengthened it.  I've tweaked the answer a little; is that enough, or was the hint for something more subtle...

Comment: Random guess - maybe the final location to search is rot13(gur svefg jbeq bs gur svefg nafjre naq gur ynfg jbeq bs gur ynfg nafjre - va jnfuvatgba, qp)?

Comment: @DanielSchepler, yep that's what I intended!

Comment: Ah - got it (thanks @DanielSchepler); I did try making it circular but kept saying "... but that's not a thing" without thinking to cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

A narrow set of rapids, perfect for rafting

> Whitewater?

-A river that started flowing off a precipice

> Waterfall

--A decrease, concering quantity or quality

---A man having this, resulting in him not playing his best

> A handicap like in sports, maybe?

----A famous painting of people at a bar

> "Nighthawks", by Edward Hopper

-----A heroic archer

> William Tell

------A beautiful woman that looked so sweet

-------A colorful town made of colorful confections

--------A mass of rock sliding down a mountain

> A landslide

---------A powerpoint presentation

> ...a ppt?

----------A platform for actors to play on a river

-----------A comfortable place to live by the water